# DIV's animated movement from an animated sliding menu disappears behind BODY or WRAPPER?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Sidebar menu has DIV that should move and stay on top of the page. I have tried setting CSS z-index, display, float. Nothing helped to make the div animate on top. Also experimented with making it dragable, Yet this didn't solve it and also is not iOS safe. So I want to stick to a simple kind of animation.

What am I missing?

How can I make the button lift up out of its menu and appear floating on top of everything? Or do I have to make a duplicate div to animate and hide the original button?

*I had to tweak a lot to fit it into a snippet, a live test is also running under: http://testing.2x2p.com*

```js
// JavaScript MyConsole Inline
function consoleMessage(cons_id,message,fatal){
// cons_id must be string id of output element
 if(typeof(cons_id)!='string'){alert('invalid console cons_id received: '+message);return false;}
 // Has dependency on moment.js
 // stamp = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
 stamp = (new Date()).getTime();
 output = document.getElementById( cons_id );
 linenr = (output.value.split("\n")).length;
 append = (linenr+": "+stamp+": "+message)
 output.value = append+"\n"+output.value;
// if fatal is 1 color change if 2 also alert the message to screen
 if(fatal){
  output.style.backgroundColor="#FC9";
  if(fatal>1){alert(message);}
 }else{
  output.style.backgroundColor="#FFC"
 }
// Has dependency on jquery.js
 var $textarea = $('#'+output.id);
 $textarea.scrollTop(0);
 return true;
}

function consoleToggleSize( cons_id, page_id ) {
 if(typeof(cons_id)!='string'){id='console-text';}
 if(typeof(page_id)!='string'){id='main-page-wrap';}
 cons = document.getElementById( cons_id );
 page = document.getElementById( page_id );
    if( cons.style.height == '24px' || cons.style.height == '' ){
    consoleMessage('console-text','console open');
  cons.style.height = '200px';
  page.style.marginBottom = '-200px';
  document.getElementById( 'console-icon' ).innerHTML = "&#8722;";
 }else{
    consoleMessage('console-text','console hide');
        cons.style.height = '24px';
  page.style.marginBottom = '-24px';
  document.getElementById( 'console-icon' ).innerHTML = "&#x2B;";
 }
}

function openMainMenu() {
  check = document.getElementById("main-menu-toggle");
  if(check.value==false){
   consoleMessage('console-text','main-menu open');
   document.getElementById("main-menu").style.width = "240px";
   document.getElementById("main-page-wrap").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
   document.getElementById("main-menu-close").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("main-menu-open").style.display = "none";
   check.value='1';
  }
}

function hideMainMenu() {
  check = document.getElementById("main-menu-toggle");
  if(check.value==true){
   consoleMessage('console-text','main-menu hide');
   document.getElementById("main-menu").style.width = "48px";
   document.getElementById("main-page-wrap").style.backgroundColor = "white";
   document.getElementById("main-menu-close").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("main-menu-open").style.display = "block";
   check.value='0';
  }
}

// JQuery based animation
function setMenuItemAnimation(menu_item_id){
  $(menu_item_id).click(function(){
 consoleMessage('console-text','animation started for '+this.id);
 $(this).css("z-index", "99999");
 $(this).css("float", "1");
    $(this).animate({
      left: "-=600px",
    }, {
      duration: 444,
      easing: "linear",
      complete: function(){
  $(this).css("z-index", "1");
  hideMainMenu();
  consoleMessage('console-text','animation ended for '+this.id);
      }
    });
  });
};

setMenuItemAnimation('#main-menu-item-1');
setMenuItemAnimation('#main-menu-item-2');
```

```css
CSS:

/* Begin main-page CSS */
.main-page-wrap {
 z-index:0;
  padding: 8px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
  height: 1px;  /*any value will do as it auto expands later*/
  margin-bottom: -24px; /* minus page-footer height */
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
 transition:             margin-bottom 333ms ease, background-color 555ms;
        -moz-transition:    margin-bottom 333ms ease, background-color 555ms;
        -ms-transition:     margin-bottom 333ms ease, background-color 555ms;
        -o-transition:      margin-bottom 333ms ease, background-color 555ms;
        -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 333ms ease, background-color 555ms;
}
.main-page-wrap:after {
}

.main-page-item {
 margin-top: -32px;
 margin-left: -48px;
}
/* Begin menu CSS */
.main-menu-wrap 
{
 background-color:inherit;
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 height:100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   min-height: 100%;
   text-align:left;
}
.main-menu-slide {
  width: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FFC;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    transition:             width 333ms ease;
        -moz-transition:    width 333ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     width 333ms ease;
        -o-transition:      width 333ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: width 333ms ease;
  height:100%;
  text-align:left;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
.main-menu-slide .main-menu-title {
 position:relative;
 width:144px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 8px 8px 16px 48px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #818181;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: 0.2s;
  display:block;
  overflow:visible;
  text-align:center;
}
.main-menu-slide .main-menu-item {
 position:relative;
 width:144px;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
  margin: 8px 8px 16px 48px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #818181;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: 0.2s;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#CCC;
  text-align:center;
 draggable="true";
  border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  box-shadow:    2px 2px 4px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:  2px 2px 4px #000;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
}
.main-menu-slide .main-menu-item:hover {
  color: #FFF;
    display:;
}
.main-menu-slide .main-menu-close {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: none;
  transition: display 0.5s;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:32px;
  cursor:   pointer;
}

.main-menu-slide .main-menu-open {
  position: relative;
  display:inline;
  top: 3px;
  left: 13px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: display 0.5s;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:32px;
  cursor:   pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .main-menu-slide {padding-top: 15px;}
  .main-menu-slide a {font-size: 18px;}
}/* Begin console CSS */
#console-text
{
  background:  inherit;
  box-sizing:  border-box;
  position:   fixed;
  top: 0;
  float:   left;
  height:   25px;
  transition:  height 333ms ease;
  -moz-transition:    height 333ms ease;
  -ms-transition:     height 333ms ease;
  -o-transition:      height 333ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: height 333ms ease;
  resize:   none;
  padding-left:  4px; 
  font-family:  monospace; 
  font-size:  17px;
  background-color: #FFC;
  overflow:   hidden;
}
.console-text, .main-page-wrap:after 
{
  height:  24px; 
  width:  100%;
}
.console-icon 
{
  position:  fixed;
  top:   0px;
  right:  5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  float:  right;
  cursor:  pointer;
  font-family: monospace; 
}

/* End console CSS */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#FFC;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='like-body'>
    <div class="main-page-wrap" id="main-page-wrap">
    <div id="main-page-content" class="main-page-item">
hello world<br>(main-page-wrap)
</div>    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-menu-wrap" id="main-menu-wrap">
<div id="main-menu" class="main-menu-slide" onMouseOver="openMainMenu()">
 <input id="main-menu-toggle" type="hidden" value="0">
    <span id="main-menu-close" class="main-menu-close" onclick="hideMainMenu()">&times;</span>
    <span id="main-menu-open" class="main-menu-open" onclick="openMainMenu()">&#9776;</span>
    <div id="main-menu-title" class="main-menu-title">
     main menu
    </div>
    <div id="main-menu-item-1" class="main-menu-item">
     click to anim
    </div>
    <div id="main-menu-item-2" class="main-menu-item">
     click to anim
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="console-wrap" onMouseUp="consoleToggleSize('console-text','main-page-wrap');">
    <textarea 
        class="console-text" 
        id="console-text" 
        cols="" 
        rows="" 
        readonly="readonly" 
        wrap="off"></textarea>
    <div id="console-icon" class="console-icon">&#x2B;</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: First, please fix your syntax errors. Then remove `javascript:` from the beginning of all your `body` event attributes.

Comment: thanks, I was able to make it run it as snippet :-)